# Convert HSL and/or RGB color to array from a string

Tags: php

I need ***convert a HSL or RGB string color to array***. I get by parameter something like:

```
$str = "rgb(40, 50, 60)"; // or "hsl(40, 50%, 60%)"
```

convert to:

```
array(40, 50, 60); // or array(50, "50%", "60%")
```

I preferer a solution using regex, I dont want to use split function ;-(

**NOTE:** 
I have a solution for RGB, but I dont work with HSL:

```
$rgb_color = sscanf($str, "rgb(%d, %d, %d)");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to look for numbers and `%` symbol, `\d` in regex find you any digits. And `preg_match_all` php function return all of the matches not just the 1st one.

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match_all('/([\d\%]+)/', 'hsl(40, 50%, 60%)', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: It's work but it create an output: `..array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "40"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "50%"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "60%"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "40"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "50%"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "60%"
  }
}`

Comment: this is the basic behavior for [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) you need the `$matches[0]`

Comment: Ops, @Peter I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for digits followed by an optional `%`:

```
preg_match_all('/([\d]+)%?/', $str, $matches);
```

Then use `$matches[1]`.

Comment: he need the `%` sign too